# pipe result to perl command

Tags: regex, perl

It may be a simple question, but I am not familar at all with perl commands. I want to pipe the result of a cut command to a perl command.

```
cut -f 1 file | perl -ne '$on=(/^>matching_pattern/) if (/^>/); print $_ if $on;' multiple_fasta_file > results.txt
```

Explanation of the commands

1. Cut the first column of the file (the results will be a string like: lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2723
2. Extract the fasta sequence that starts with > and a matching pattern which is the result of the cut command: lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2723) in a multiple_fasta_file

Multiple_fasta_sequence:

>lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2722
ACTCCCCGTGCGCGCCCGGCCCGTAGCGTCCTCGTCGCCGCCCCTCGTCTCGCAGCCGCAGCCCGCGTGGACGCTCTCGCCTGAGCGCCGCGGACTAGCCCGGGTGGCC
>lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2723
CAGTCCGGCAGCGCCGGGGTTAAGCGGCCCAAGTAAACGTAGCGCAGCGATCGGCGCCGGAGATTCGCGAACCCGACACTCCGCGCCGCCCGCCGGCCAGGACCCGCGGCGCGATCGCGGCGCCGCGCTACAGCCAGCCTCACTGGCGCGCGGGCGAGCGCACGGGCGCTC
>lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2724
CACGACAGGCCCGCTGAGGCTTGTGCCAGACCTTGGAAACCTCAGGTATATACCTTTCCAGACGCGGGATCTCCCCTCCCC

Result of cut: lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2723
Result of perl:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              >lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2723
CAGTCCGGCAGCGCCGGGGTTAAGCGGCCCAAGTAAACGTAGCGCAGCGATCGGCGCCGGAGATTCGCGAACCCGACACTCCGCGCCGCCCGCGGCCAGGACCCGCGGCGCGATCGCGGCGCCGCGCTACAGCCAGCCTCACTGGCGCGCGGGCGAGCGCACGGGCGCTC

It is possible to do it without declaring a variable?

Comment: What's the role of `multiple_fasta_file`? Your present example reads it. And what is `file`, the argument of `cut`?

Comment: `?` is a regex metacharacter.  What are you trying to match?  Consider providing an example.

Comment: @ SzG                                                             The multiple_fasta_file is a file containing thousand of fasta sequences and with the perl command I extract only one sequence of that file starting with > and the matching caracter ???. The file in the cut command is an arguments of cut (tsv file with several columns and I cut the first column of that file).

Comment: Yes.. Did I miss something? The ouput (result of the perl) should be identical to the sequence: >lcl|NC_017656.1_gene_2723 CAGTCCGGCAGCGCCGGGGTTAAGCGGCCCAAGTAAACGTAGCGCAGCGATCGGCGCCGGAGATTCGCGAACCCGACACTCCGCGCCGCCCGCCGGCCAGGACCCGCGGCGCGATCGCGGCGCCGCGCTACAGCCAGCCTCACTGGCGCGCGGGCGAGCGCACGGGCGCTC in the multiple_fasta_file

Comment: The file and the multiple_fasta_files aren't the same. The file (tsv file) is the input for the cut command and the multiple_fasta_file is the input file for the perl command.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad answer, as it's rather a question.
Did not you mean this?

```
cut -f 1 multiple_fasta_file | perl -ne '$on = 1 if /^>\?\?\?/; print if $on' > results.txt
```

- just read `multiple_fasta_file`
- in case of literal question marks, you have to escape them (? is the zero-or-one regex quantifier)
- check only once for `/^>/`
- remove unnecessary punctuation to improve readability

Comment: Thanks for your answer but maybe I wasn't clear enought. The file of the cut command is not the same as the multiple_fasta_file. I know the commands I wrote in the question works but I want to know how I can replace the matching_pattern in the perl command by the output of the command cut (using something like $1)